# Which JS events apart from `click` will successfully activate the Fullscreen API?

Tags: javascript, events, html5-fullscreen

I've been refactoring some javascript.

Previously, I had an HTML element open to [**Fullscreen**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) when the user clicked on another element.

Now clicking the latter element initiates a server-side verification, instead.

Once the server-side verification check passes, the page reloads with extra data confirming the user is verified.

> **N.B.** When the page reloads, it does so with a non-negligible amount of extra markup, styles, scripts and vectors. The reason I am re-factoring in the first place is to avoid the need to download all these extra assets (and keep them in the background, on standby) unless and until the user authenticates themselves

The first thing I discovered is that I *cannot* have the page reload and *then* have the HTML element immediately open to **Fullscreen**, because - and this seems entirely reasonable from a UX perspective, Firefox reports:

> Request for fullscreen was denied because `Element.requestFullscreen()` was not called from inside a short running user-generated event handler.

Essentially, *unless the user **pro-actively** interacts with the page*, the **Fullscreen API** will not run.

(In this scenario, the user pro-actively interacted with the page *before reload*, which is not the same thing.)

So, I thought about it and then added:

```
document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', () => myElement.requestFullscreen(), {once: true});
```

Nope. The **Fullscreen API** still doesn't activate.

To check that I wasn't making an elementary error somewhere else, I tried:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', () => myElement.requestFullscreen(), {once: true});
```

Which **does** work.

So: some user-interactions will successfully fire the **Fullscreen API** and others won't.

I have searched through the [*WHAT-WG HTML Spec*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/) but I cannot find a list of events which represent explicit and pro-active user-interactions on a webpage.

Does such a list exist?

Which other events apart from `click` will successfully activate the **Fullscreen API**?

Comment: You need the consent of the user -> actively click something. Moving the mouse is no consent. The web would be full of full-screen adds if that would be enough. Get rid of the page reload part -> AJAX

Comment: @Andreas - Thanks. Yes, Ajax (or, probably, Fetch API) would be a feasible approach if **Constructable Stylesheets** had cross-browser support. But AFAIK at present, outside Chrome, Mozilla only supports in Firefox Nightly and there has been very little movement from Safari.

Comment: Where's the connection between CSS and AJAX? o.O

Comment: @Andreas - sorry, i don't understand your question. I've added more detail above to (hopefully) describe my setup with greater clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which JS events apart from `click` will successfully activate the **Fullscreen API**?

A small number of events will successfully activate the **Fullscreen API**.

Almost all of these events either imply a user-click or directly reference one:

- change
- click
- contextmenu
- dblclick
- mouseup
- pointerup
- reset
- submit
- touchend

Further to the list of click-based events above, the **Fullscreen API** may also be activated via:

- [ScreenOrientation.onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScreenOrientation/onchange)

---

**Source:**

- https://www.aworkinprogress.dev/request-fullscreen